# CommandBars, Buttons and Commands: Take 3

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, rubberduck, ninject

Following up on [CommandBars, Buttons and Commands: Take 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98979/commandbars-buttons-and-commands-take-2), I've refactored quite a lot of the Rubberduck code base (like, a whole third of the entire code base has been affected), and successfully untangled the `RubberduckMenu` and gave each command its own place to be.

So, "Shared" commands that can be executed from the main "Rubberduck" menu, or from the *code pane* context menu, or a COM `CommandBar`, WinForms `Toolstrip` or WPF `Button`, can be easily reused. These commands derive from the `CommandBase` abstract class, which implements the WPF `ICommand` interface:

**CommandBase** abstract class

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Rubberduck.UI.Command
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
    {
        public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public abstract void Execute(object parameter);

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        protected void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is one such "shared" command:

**RunAllTestsCommand** implementation

```
using Rubberduck.UI.UnitTesting;
using Rubberduck.UnitTesting;

namespace Rubberduck.UI.Command
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A command that runs all Rubberduck unit tests in the VBE.
    /// </summary>
    public class RunAllTestsCommand : CommandBase
    {
        private readonly ITestEngine _engine;
        private readonly TestExplorerModelBase _model;

        public RunAllTestsCommand(ITestEngine engine, TestExplorerModelBase model)
        {
            _engine = engine;
            _model = model;
        }

        public override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _model.Refresh();
            _model.ClearLastRun();
            _engine.Run(_model.Tests);
        }
    }
}
```

There are many, may other commands (quite a bunch yet to be actually implemented), but the idea is the same: "shared" commands get their dependencies in their constructor, and can be called from anywhere; commands that are specific to a given ViewModel (say, the "export inspection results" command in the `CodeInspectionResultsViewModel`), are implemented in that ViewModel as `DelegateCommand`s - the result is a decoupled architecture, that the IoC container brings together.

The IoC container being Ninject, I've implemented a `NinjectModule` dedicated to configuring the menus and command bars - works great, but I'd like it cleaner; any ideas?

**CommandBarsModule** class

```
namespace Rubberduck.Root
{
    public class CommandBarsModule : NinjectModule
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        public CommandBarsModule(IKernel kernel)
        {
            _kernel = kernel;
        }

        public override void Load()
        {
            BindCommandsToMenuItems();

            ConfigureRubberduckMenu();
            ConfigureCodePaneContextMenu();
            ConfigureFormDesignerContextMenu();
            ConfigureFormDesignerControlContextMenu();
            ConfigureProjectExplorerContextMenu();
        }

        private void ConfigureRubberduckMenu()
        {
            const int windowMenuId = 30009;
            var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars["Menu Bar"].Controls;
            var beforeIndex = FindRubberduckMenuInsertionIndex(parent, windowMenuId);

            var items = GetRubberduckMenuItems();
            BindParentMenuItem<RubberduckParentMenu>(parent, beforeIndex, items);
        }

        private void ConfigureCodePaneContextMenu()
        {
            const int listMembersMenuId = 2529;
            var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars["Code Window"].Controls;
            var beforeIndex = parent.Cast<CommandBarControl>().First(control => control.Id == listMembersMenuId).Index;

            var items = GetCodePaneContextMenuItems();
            BindParentMenuItem<RubberduckParentMenu>(parent, beforeIndex, items);
        }

        private void ConfigureFormDesignerContextMenu()
        {
            const int viewCodeMenuId = 2558;
            var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars["MSForms"].Controls;
            var beforeIndex = parent.Cast<CommandBarControl>().First(control => control.Id == viewCodeMenuId).Index;

            var items = GetFormDesignerContextMenuItems();
            BindParentMenuItem<FormDesignerContextParentMenu>(parent, beforeIndex, items);
        }

        private void ConfigureFormDesignerControlContextMenu()
        {
            const int viewCodeMenuId = 2558;
            var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars["MSForms Control"].Controls;
            var beforeIndex = parent.Cast<CommandBarControl>().First(control => control.Id == viewCodeMenuId).Index;

            var items = GetFormDesignerContextMenuItems();
            BindParentMenuItem<FormDesignerControlContextParentMenu>(parent, beforeIndex, items);
        }

        private void ConfigureProjectExplorerContextMenu()
        {
            const int projectPropertiesMenuId = 2578;
            var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars["Project Window"].Controls;
            var beforeIndex = parent.Cast<CommandBarControl>().First(control => control.Id == projectPropertiesMenuId).Index;

            var items = GetProjectWindowContextMenuItems();
            BindParentMenuItem<ProjectWindowContextParentMenu>(parent, beforeIndex, items);
        }

        private void BindParentMenuItem<TParentMenu>(CommandBarControls parent, int beforeIndex, IEnumerable<IMenuItem> items)
        {
            _kernel.Bind<IParentMenuItem>().To(typeof(TParentMenu))
                .InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("items", items)
                .WithConstructorArgument("beforeIndex", beforeIndex)
                .WithPropertyValue("Parent", parent);
        }

        private static int FindRubberduckMenuInsertionIndex(CommandBarControls controls, int beforeId)
        {
            for (var i = 1; i <= controls.Count; i++)
            {
                if (controls[i].BuiltIn && controls[i].Id == beforeId)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return controls.Count;
        }

        private void BindCommandsToMenuItems()
        {
            //_kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To<NavigateCommand>().InSingletonScope();
            _kernel.Bind<IDeclarationNavigator>().To<NavigateAllImplementations>().WhenTargetHas<FindImplementationsAttribute>().InSingletonScope();
            _kernel.Bind<IDeclarationNavigator>().To<NavigateAllReferences>().WhenTargetHas<FindReferencesAttribute>().InSingletonScope();

            var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.StartsWith(typeof(CommandBase).Namespace ?? string.Empty))
                .ToList();

            // note: ICommand naming convention: [Foo]Command
            var commands = types.Where(type => type.IsClass && type.BaseType == typeof(CommandBase) && type.Name.EndsWith("Command"));
            foreach (var command in commands)
            {
                var commandName = command.Name.Substring(0, command.Name.Length - "Command".Length);
                try
                {
                    // note: ICommandMenuItem naming convention for [Foo]Command: [Foo]CommandMenuItem
                    var item = types.SingleOrDefault(type => type.Name == commandName + "CommandMenuItem");
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        _kernel.Bind(item).ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
                        _kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To(command).WhenInjectedInto(item).InSingletonScope();
                    }
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
                {
                    // rename one of the classes, "FooCommand" is expected to match exactly 1 "FooBarXyzCommandMenuItem"
                }
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<IMenuItem> GetRubberduckMenuItems()
        {
            return new IMenuItem[]
            {
                _kernel.Get<AboutCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<OptionsCommandMenuItem>(), 
                _kernel.Get<RunCodeInspectionsCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<ShowSourceControlPanelCommandMenuItem>(), 
                GetUnitTestingParentMenu(),
                GetRefactoringsParentMenu(),
                GetNavigateParentMenu(),
            };
        }

        private IMenuItem GetUnitTestingParentMenu()
        {
            var items = new IMenuItem[]
            {
                _kernel.Get<RunAllTestsCommandMenuItem>(), 
                _kernel.Get<TestExplorerCommandMenuItem>(), 
                _kernel.Get<AddTestModuleCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<AddTestMethodCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<AddTestMethodExpectedErrorCommandMenuItem>(),
            };

            return new UnitTestingParentMenu(items);
        }

        private IMenuItem GetRefactoringsParentMenu()
        {
            var items = new IMenuItem[]
            {
                _kernel.Get<RefactorRenameCommandMenuItem>(), 
                _kernel.Get<RefactorExtractMethodCommandMenuItem>(), 
                _kernel.Get<RefactorReorderParametersCommandMenuItem>(), 
                _kernel.Get<RefactorRemoveParametersCommandMenuItem>(), 
            };

            return new RefactoringsParentMenu(items);
        }

        private IMenuItem GetNavigateParentMenu()
        {
            var items = new IMenuItem[]
            {
                _kernel.Get<CodeExplorerCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<ToDoExplorerCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<FindSymbolCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<FindAllReferencesCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<FindAllImplementationsCommandMenuItem>(),
            };
            return new NavigateParentMenu(items);
        }

        private IEnumerable<IMenuItem> GetCodePaneContextMenuItems()
        {
            return new IMenuItem[]
            {
                GetRefactoringsParentMenu(),
                _kernel.Get<FindSymbolCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<FindAllReferencesCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<FindAllImplementationsCommandMenuItem>(),
            };
        }

        private IEnumerable<IMenuItem> GetFormDesignerContextMenuItems()
        {
            return new IMenuItem[]
            {
                _kernel.Get<RefactorRenameCommandMenuItem>(), 
            };
        }

        private IEnumerable<IMenuItem> GetProjectWindowContextMenuItems()
        {
            return new IMenuItem[]
            {
                _kernel.Get<RefactorRenameCommandMenuItem>(), 
                _kernel.Get<FindSymbolCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<FindAllReferencesCommandMenuItem>(),
                _kernel.Get<FindAllImplementationsCommandMenuItem>(),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These four methods contain a lot of duplication:

> ```
> private void ConfigureCodePaneContextMenu()
> {
>   const int listMembersMenuId = 2529;
>   var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars["Code Window"].Controls;
>   var beforeIndex = parent.Cast<CommandBarControl>().First(control => control.Id == listMembersMenuId).Index;
>
>   var items = GetCodePaneContextMenuItems();
>   BindParentMenuItem<RubberduckParentMenu>(parent, beforeIndex, items);
> }
>
> private void ConfigureFormDesignerContextMenu()
> {
>   const int viewCodeMenuId = 2558;
>   var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars["MSForms"].Controls;
>   var beforeIndex = parent.Cast<CommandBarControl>().First(control => control.Id == viewCodeMenuId).Index;
>
>   var items = GetFormDesignerContextMenuItems();
>   BindParentMenuItem<FormDesignerContextParentMenu>(parent, beforeIndex, items);
> }
>
> private void ConfigureFormDesignerControlContextMenu()
> {
>   const int viewCodeMenuId = 2558;
>   var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars["MSForms Control"].Controls;
>   var beforeIndex = parent.Cast<CommandBarControl>().First(control => control.Id == viewCodeMenuId).Index;
>
>   var items = GetFormDesignerContextMenuItems();
>   BindParentMenuItem<FormDesignerControlContextParentMenu>(parent, beforeIndex, items);
> }
>
> private void ConfigureProjectExplorerContextMenu()
> {
>   const int projectPropertiesMenuId = 2578;
>   var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars["Project Window"].Controls;
>   var beforeIndex = parent.Cast<CommandBarControl>().First(control => control.Id == projectPropertiesMenuId).Index;
>
>   var items = GetProjectWindowContextMenuItems();
>   BindParentMenuItem<ProjectWindowContextParentMenu>(parent, beforeIndex, items);
> }
> ```

Let's start by introducing a method `ConfigureContextMenu`:

```
private void ConfigureCodePaneContextMenu()
{
    const int listMembersMenuId = 2529;
    ConfigureContextMenu<RubberduckParentMenu>(listMembersMenuId, "Code Window", GetCodePaneContextMenuItems());
}

private void ConfigureFormDesignerContextMenu()
{
    const int viewCodeMenuId = 2558;
    ConfigureContextMenu<FormDesignerContextParentMenu>(viewCodeMenuId, "MSForms", GetFormDesignerContextMenuItems());
}

private void ConfigureFormDesignerControlContextMenu()
{
    const int viewCodeMenuId = 2558;
    ConfigureContextMenu<FormDesignerControlContextParentMenu>(viewCodeMenuId, "MSForms Control", GetFormDesignerContextMenuItems());
}

private void ConfigureProjectExplorerContextMenu()
{
    const int projectPropertiesMenuId = 2578;
    ConfigureContextMenu<ProjectWindowContextParentMenu>(projectPropertiesMenuId, "Project Window", GetProjectWindowContextMenuItems());
}

private void ConfigureContextMenu<T>(int menuId, string commandBarId, IEnumerable<IMenuItem> menuItems)
{
    var parent = _kernel.Get<VBE>().CommandBars[commandBarId].Controls;
    var beforeIndex = parent.Cast<CommandBarControl>().First(control => control.Id == menuId).Index;
    BindParentMenuItem<T>(parent, beforeIndex, menuItems);
}
```

By doing this we can see that they aren't really so much different methods, as they are the same method operating on different data.

You could take it a step further and introduce a private class `ContextMenuConfiguration`:

```
const int listMembersMenuId = 2529;
const int viewCodeMenuId = 2558;
const int projectPropertiesMenuId = 2578;

var codePaneContextMenuConfiguration =
    new ContextMenuConfiguration(listMembersMenuId, "Code Window", GetCodePaneContextMenuItems(), typeof(RubberduckParentMenu));

var formDesignerContextMenuConfiguration =
    new ContextMenuConfiguration(viewCodeMenuId, "MSForms", GetFormDesignerContextMenuItems(), typeof(FormDesignerContextParentMenu));

var formDesignerControlContextMenuConfiguration =
    new ContextMenuConfiguration(viewCodeMenuId, "MSForms Control", GetFormDesignerContextMenuItems(), typeof(FormDesignerControlContextParentMenu));

var projectExplorerContextMenuConfiguration =
    new ContextMenuConfiguration(projectPropertiesMenuId, "Project Window", GetProjectWindowContextMenuItems(), typeof(ProjectWindowContextParentMenu));

var contextMenuConfigurations = new[]
{
    codePaneContextMenuConfiguration,
    formDesignerContextMenuConfiguration,
    formDesignerControlContextMenuConfiguration,
    projectExplorerContextMenuConfiguration
};

foreach (var configuration in contextMenuConfigurations)
{
    ConfigureContextMenu(configuration);
}
```